# How do you conditionally render dynamically created child components in React? Specifically: components created via mapping over JSON

Tags: reactjs

I'm rendering some components via mapping over JSON, each containing a div which further contains two divs and their respective children components. I'd like a button in 'child component a' to trigger a show/hide css class for 'child component b', but specifically the instance related to where it was triggered, while keeping the logic in the parent. My first thought is to use an ID to conditionally set the classes but am having a hard time conceptualizing the logic. Currently just using hooks and not really familiar with Redux but something tells me that might be required here. Any ideas or guidance?

Some more detail for context: It's a color palette app which pulls data from an API and renders 5 colors. Each color (child component a) has a button to open its corresponding editor (child component b). Initially I had the editor within the color component which removes this problem entirely but then I had the issue of not being able to control their collisions (multiple editors open at the same time). I of course could hard code all five (10) components individually but I know that's not the right solution and would prevent some future features (dynamically controlling number of colors for instance).

Another issue I'm having here is that passing the useState value down as props does not translate (editorVisible) in the child. for instance console.log(editorVisible)in the parent returns it's boolean value but in the child returns undefined. Could use some insight here as well.

Parent Code: This code, as expected, sets the class for all five editors. I need a solution to target them individually while maintaining the rendering via map:

```
const ComposerPane = () => {
  const colors = data
  const [editorVisible, setEditorVisible] = useState()
  const [editorInitialClass, setEditorInitialclass] = useState('editor-container-initial')

  const toggle = () => {
    console.log(editorVisible)
    setEditorVisible(!editorVisible)
    setEditorInitialclass('editor-animate-return')
  }
  
  const editColor = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className='composer-container'>
      {colors.map((color) => (
        <div key={color.id} className='composer-fix'>
          <div className="color-comp-container">
            <ColorComp
              id={color.id}
              red={color.red}
              green={color.green}
              blue={color.blue}
              hex={color.hex}
              toggle={toggle}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={
            editorVisible ?
              'editor-container editor-animate' :
              `${editorInitialClass} editor-container`
          }>
            <Editor
              id={color.id}
              red={color.red}
              green={color.green}
              blue={color.blue}
              hex={color.hex}
              editColor={editColor}
              editorVisible={editorVisible}
              editorInitialClass={editorInitialClass}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And the individual color child component:

```
const ColorComp = ({ id, red, green, blue, hex, toggle, editorVisible, editorInitialClass }) => {

  // Sets new color to color object
  const BGcolorValue = Color.rgb(parseInt(red), parseInt(green), parseInt(blue))

  // Background-color css
  const BGColor = { backgroundColor: `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})` }

  // Sets text and icon color value based on background
  const foreColor = BGcolorValue.isLight() ? 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)' : 'rgba(255,255,255,.5)'

  // CSS values
  const hexStyle = { color: foreColor }
  const indicatorStyle = { backgroundColor: foreColor }
  const iconFillStyle = { fill: foreColor }

  return (
    <div className='color-comp' style={BGColor}>
      <div className={editorVisible ?
        'editorIndicatorContainer editor-animate' :
        `${editorInitialClass} editorIndicatorContainer`
      }>
        <p className='hexIndicator' style={hexStyle}>#{hex.toUpperCase()}</p>
        <div className='editorIndicator' style={indicatorStyle} />
      </div>
      <CustomButton
        onClick={() => {
        toggle();
        console.log(editorVisible);
        }}
        foreColor={foreColor}
        className='editorIcon'
        style={iconFillStyle}><EditorIcon /></CustomButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The editor component:

```
const Editor = ({ id, red, green, blue, editColor }) => {
  return (
  <div className='editor' id={id}>
    <div className='EditorPane'>
      <button className='EditorButton Done'>DONE</button>
      <div className='Slider'>
        <p className='SliderLabel'>R:</p>
        <input className='SliderInput' type='text' value={red} onChange={editColor}></input>
        <input className='EditorSlider' name='red' type='range' min='0' max='255' value={red} onChange={editColor}/>
      </div>
      <div className='Slider'>
        <p className='SliderLabel'>G:</p>
        <input className='SliderInput' type='text' value={green} onChange={editColor}></input>
        <input className='EditorSlider' name='green' type='range' min='0' max='255' value={green} onChange={editColor}/>
      </div>
      <div className='Slider'>
        <p className='SliderLabel'>B:</p>
        <input className='SliderInput' type='text' value={blue} onChange={editColor}/>
        <input className='EditorSlider' name='blue' type='range' min='0' max='255' value={blue} onChange={editColor}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: To point you in the right direction, you can unlock a lot of power by storing the active color ID in state instead of the `editorVisible` boolean. If the editor should be closed, set the `activeColorId` state to `null`. That one piece of state now tells you whether or not to display the editor, as well as which color triggered it. You can pass that ID around and do some cool things, e.g. highlighting the active color swatch. You don't need Redux for this :)

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes perfect sense, will give this a go.